# max date record in LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, linq, max

I have this table named sample with these values in MS Sql Server:

```
 ID    Date    Description
1    2012/01/02 5:12:43    Desc1
2    2012/01/02 5:12:48    Desc2
3    2012/01/03 5:12:41    Desc3
4    2012/01/03 5:12:43    Desc4
```

Now I want to write LINQ query that result will be this:

```
4    2012/01/03 5:12:43    Desc4
```

I wrote this but it doesn't work:

```
List<Sample> q = (from n in  Sample.Max(T=>T.Date)).ToList();
```

Comment: where is your `select` ?

Comment: *doesn't work* -- Please elaborate.

Comment: @GertArnold - The OP hasn't had any activity in 9 years.

Comment: @Enigmativity I know, I leave such comments anyway to indicate in general that questions shouldn't be asked this way.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Starting from **.NET 6** [`MaxBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.maxby) LINQ method is available.

```
var result = items.MaxBy(i => i.Date);
```

---

Prior to .NET 6:

O(n):

```
var result = items.Aggregate((x, y) => x.Date > y.Date ? x : y);
```

O(n) – but iterates over the sequence twice:

```
var max = items.Max(i => i.Date);
var result = items.First(i => i.Date == max);
```

O(n log n):

```
var result = items.OrderByDescending(i => i.Date).First();
```

Comment: Note that `MaxBy` is not supported by EF Core ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70259759/net-6-new-linq-features-with-entity-framework/70259933#70259933))

Answer (score 28):

To get the maximum `Sample` value by date *without* having to sort (which is not really necessary to just get the maximum):

```
var maxSample  = Samples.Where(s => s.Date == Samples.Max(x => x.Date))
                        .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: this has the same complexity as the accepted answer that requires ordering, as far as I understand

Comment: @knocte no it's not the same complexity - this is O(n) - 2 passes needed, each O(n)  - sorting would be O(n log n) so more expensive

Comment: ok cool, could it be written in a way to have only 1 pass? the point of using LINQ is having less imperative code, but with the same or better performance

Comment: yes - it definitely could be written with an old school `foreach` loop in one pass, just got to keep the `Sample` instance around that has the max date so far.

Comment: right, so in this case using foreach(imperative) style is more efficient than LINQ? :(

Comment: You *could* still write it with Linq, e.g. using `Aggregate` but it would be nowhere near as readable imo, so I wouldn't consider it

Comment: Well, the thing is, if you're querying using LINQ over an IQueryable<> collection, you want the query to be as performant as possible in order to be converted to less SQL queries as possible by EntityFramework. So readability in this case is not as important as efficiency, especially if you have many rows in the table.

Comment: This looks `O(n^2)` to me. The max is recomputed every iteration of the where clause.

Comment: @BrokenGlass - The `Max` should be separated out to avoid `O(n^2)`.

Answer (score 5):

```
var lastInstDate = model.Max(i=>i.ScheduleDate);
```

> We can get max date from the model like this.

Comment: Not sure why this isn't voted up more. By far the easiest and most efficient

Comment: @FrankCastle616 it doesn't actually answer the question. This returns a date, not the record containing that date

Answer (score 2):

```
List<Sample> q = Sample.OrderByDescending(T=>T.Date).Take(1).ToList();
```

But I think you want

```
Sample q = Sample.OrderByDescending(T=>T.Date).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a single pass option:

```
var maxSample =
    Samples
        .Aggregate((x, y) => x.Date < y.Date ? y : x);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
IList<Student> studentList = new List<Student>() { 
    new Student() { StudentID = 1, StudentName = "John", Age = 18 } ,
    new Student() { StudentID = 2, StudentName = "Steve",  Age = 15 } ,
    new Student() { StudentID = 3, StudentName = "Bill",  Age = 25 } ,
    new Student() { StudentID = 4, StudentName = "Ram" , Age = 20 } ,
    new Student() { StudentID = 5, StudentName = "Ron" , Age = 19 } 
};

var orderByDescendingResult = from s in studentList
                   orderby s.StudentName descending
                   select s;
```

Result : 
Steve
Ron
Ram
John
Bill

Comment: This is exactly the same as the accepted answer.

Answer (score -3):

```
var result= Sample.OrderByDescending(k => k.ID).FirstOrDefault().Date;
```

This is the best way to do this

Comment: This is exactly the same as the accepted answer.