# LINQ match on latest date from 2 columns

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, max

Give this Linq query:

```
GetData.Where(p => p.LastActionA >= startDate && p.LastActionA <= endDate)
```

How could I change it so I can match on the highest value from 2 date columns?

ie something like  `GetData.Where(MAX(p.LastActionA, p.LastActionB) >= startDate`

The closest equivalent SQL I can get uses a subquery, something like this:

```
SELECT ID,
  (SELECT MAX(v)  FROM (VALUES (LastActionA), (LastActionB)) AS value(v)) as MaxDate
FROM Data
```

Comment: I think you could use some of what was done in this Stack Overflow post to get what you want: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9143146/max-date-record-in-linq)

Comment: EF6 or EF Core?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For just 2 dates, you could use the C# conditional operator (works in both latest EF6 and EF Core):

```
.Where(p => (p.LastActionA > p.LastActionB ? p.LastActionA : p.LastActionB) >= startDate)
```

The following works for 2 and more dates, but only in EF6 (generates worse SQL). Actually it works in EF Core too, but causes client evaluation, which is bad:

```
.Where(p => new [] { p.LastActionA, p.LastActionB }.Max() >= startDate)
```