# .NET 6 New LINQ Features with Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server, sqlite, entity-framework, linq, .net-6.0

In .NET 6 there are some nice new LINQ extension methods, e.g.

```
var oldest = context.People.MaxBy(p => p.Age);
```

However, these features do not yet seem to be supported by EF providers (certainly not SQLite or SQLServer, both version 6.0.0).

Does anyone know when these are planned to be available in these providers?

Comment: Are they not available on `Queryable`?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary They're available on the interface but implemented by the provider.

Comment: What would be the equivalent in SQL? LINQ gets translated to SQL , so it can't do anything that isn't possible in SQL.

Comment: LINQ doesn't run by itself, it gets translated to SQL. All queries that would perform the equivalent of `MaxBy` have a high cost. `select * from Table1 where field=(select max(field) from Table1)` is expensive, even if `field` is covered by an index. If not, it's **very** expensive. Using `ROW_NUMBER` is also expensive but *maybe* it can get the result with only a single table scan - provided the indexes are just right. `select top 1 * from Table1 order by field desc` requires a sort too. And what happens with *related* objects?

Comment: yea it's just a simple `order by (x) desc` and getting the first result

Answer (score 5):

Currently they are not supported by EF Core (at least by providers shipped by EF Core team) and are investigated by the team for support in 7.0. See [this](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/25566) github issue.

And [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/25570) for other new LINQ features.

Comment: Don't expect much. The key phrase is `reasonable translations.`. There aren't many, and all are expensive. Then there's the matter of loading related entities