# Best way to rewrite a groupby / orderby query in LINQ to objects

Tags: c#, linq, morelinq

I have some data looking like this :

```
Environment | Time
"1" | 2021/09/01
"2" | 2021/09/02
"1" | 2021/09/03
"3" | 2021/09/01
"1" | 2021/09/03
"1" | 2021/09/04
"3" | 2021/12/01
"2" | 2021/11/02
```

I need to find the last record (by time) for each environment, so I wrote :

```
var lastPerEnvironment = data
    .GroupBy(prp => prp.Environment)
    .Select(prp => prp.OrderByDescending(o => o.Time).First());
```

Of course it works as expected, but I guess there's a simpler way to write it and maybe also more efficient, using a convening library like MoreLINQ for example (or another good to know library ?), with some kind of partitioning.

I do not need the Linq to SQL translation (but it would be nice if it was also supported by the suggested solution), only Linq to Objects.

Thanks for suggestions

Comment: It's more like a code-review if it works. A better way could be by instead of putting it all in one list, create separate lists in a dictionary with Environment as key. Fill it while parsing the data. This way you don't have to group it.

Comment: @GertArnold I mentioned it but I was not able to find a method matching my need in it, which does not mean that method does not exist, or there is no other library that can help

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen a such implementation will not be shorter and it will probably be slower, as Dictionary implies to fully evaluate all items of the IEnumerable. But it would be interesting if my purpose was to keep each environment separated. I could also have done some kind of Lookup instead of Groupby.

Comment: @AFract Eventually a groupby will evaluate all items of the IEnumerable as wel. It was just a thought.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen you're right, but I still don't need the dictionary ;). Even if the group by / order is quite easy to understand, it's a bit long, the idea was to find a direct method that gives the same behavior and returns a list with only each last item of each group. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to [this SO response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9143173):
optimize your `prp.OrderByDescending(o => o.Time).First()` by `MaxBy(o => o.Date);` ([native in .NET 6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.maxby?view=net-6.0) but also available in [MoreLINQ](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ#maxby))

Comment: MaxBy is not the correct method.

Comment: I noticed this method, but I was confused by it because MaxBy (from MoreLinq as I'm in .Net 5.0) returns a "IExtremaEnumerable<T>" and not a single element. https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/MaxBy.cs

Comment: From my understanding, that's because you can have many result with the exact same value (same date in your case). You'll probably have to pick the first element from this result in your case

Comment: As I said, it's not the correct method. It should be DistinctBy.